# What is a software solution that provides 1 on 1 video chat?

Tags: web, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc, tokbox

We've made an application where two people can video chat with each other using TokBox, but are running into a **lot** of technical issues surrounding WebRTC and TokBox itself. I know that Twilio recently launched a Javascript version for their video service, but both TokBox and Twilio seem to be aiming for larger scale publish/subscribe operations. It also isn't as far along as TokBox.

Are there other services out there that can do web video 1 on 1's? Perhaps some that don't use WebRTC and therefore don't have the problems we are facing?

I can't help but to think back to ChatRoulette and similar apps.

Answer (score 2):

If what you need is an application that needs to run within the context of a browser, then WebRTC is your only choice when it comes to the technology to use. There's just nothing else there now that Flash is officially dead.

If you need it to run purely inside a packaged PC/mobile application, then you can use something other than WebRTC, but I don't really see the need for that.

When using real time video technologies, one aspect to look at closely is the quality of the network you are using. The questions I usually ask myself are things like does Skype/Hangouts/FaceTime run any better? If the answer is "yes they do", then the problem is in the implementation you have done/used. If the answer is "no, they are just as bad" then you probably can't do a lot better either.

For alternatives, you can check out the vendors listed in this WebRTC Develoepr Tools Landscape: https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-developer-tools-landscape/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean with "a lot of technical issues surrounding WebRTC and Tokbox itself", but I do know Tokbox handles millions of 1:1 streaming minutes every day, without issues, and it can even handle sessions with 1 publisher and 3000 subscribers at the same time, so, maybe the technical issues are not there, but in another place...